# Swagger-codegen for Java: models that share names with built-in classes

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen

I have a specification that calls for a model named `File` and the model is in  `definitions`, as prescribed.  Swagger-Editor says this specification is valid and even shows the `File` model at the bottom with its own properties.

However, when I attempt to generate the code for this specification, swagger-codegen does not create a `io.swagger.model.File` class, but instead uses `java.io.File`.

I would imagine this is because locating the 'File' symbol is trivial, and it goes ahead and uses that located symbol from the JDK library. Is there a way to force swagger-codegen to create the `io.swagger.model.File` class according to how it is described in the `definitions`, instead of this short-circuit resolution?

Comment: Please open a ticket in https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/new so that we can help you out. I can think of more than1 way to tackle the problem.

Comment: @WilliamCheng Created issue ticket #7064 [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/7064).  Thank you for the response.